# Reading multiple numbers on a single line with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I need to read multiple numbers (don't know how many numbers I'm going to read, but I know they are at most six numbers) from a single line using a Scanner. I tried something found on the net but I couldn't find a solution. The reading stops when the user writes -1. Here's what I wrote up to now:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
float buffer[] = new float[6];

while (read.nextInt() != -1) {
            if (read.hasNextInt()) {
                buffer[i] = read.nextInt();
                i++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

When I try to run this, I get a `NoSuchElementException`, but I don't understand why. What's wrong with this code? How can I correct this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't checking if the `Scanner` has another `int` (and a `Scanner` doesn't return `-1` when it does not have another element). This

```
while (read.nextInt() != -1) {
```

needs to be something like

```
while (read.hasNextInt()) {
    int val = read.nextInt();
    if (val == -1) {
        break;
    }
    buffer[i] = val;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can read line once, and split it in integers

```
   line=scanner.nextLine();

   // split there
   String elements[]=line.split("\\W+");

   // convert to int    
   for (int i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
       ints[counter++]=Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);

   // check
   for (int i=0;i<counter;i++)
       System.out.println("INT ["+i+"]:"+ints[i]);
```